# Query of a MySQL database in C++ not returning all values

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-workbench

Its a bit of a new topic for myself. I'm learning to connect to SQL databases through C++. Right now i have a table that's being used to connect to a local SQL server. On the server is a schema containing basic garbage data that was used for a lab at the start of the semester (I've been using the data to figure out different SQL syntax)

**In this case, the server used is MySql Workbench.**
We were given some basic instructions on setting up Visual Studio to communicate with this sql database and query data. While it works to some extent it seems to refuse to return the full table of data.
In SQL, if i want to query a table named `offices`, where the `officeCode` I want to view is '1', I'd simply type `SELECT * FROM offices WHERE officeCode = 1;`

this same query on visual studio seems to only return everything EXCEPT the first row. Even if i broaden it so it doesn't use the "where" constraint, it still refuses to return the very first entry into the table. I'm not sure if its the way I've set up the code, or maybe its not connecting to my db right, does anyone else spot something that i haven't?

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;
int main() {
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "127.0.0.1", "<ommittedUser>", "<omittedPass>", "new_schema", 3306, nullptr, 0);

    if (conn) {
        cout << "successful connection to database" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Connection failed!" << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM offices WHERE officeCode = 1 ;"; //doesnt detect the first row
    const char* q = query.c_str();
    int exequery;
    exequery = mysql_query(conn, q);

    if (!exequery) {
        cout << "The query executed successfully with no error." << endl;
        res = mysql_store_result(conn);
        if (mysql_fetch_row(res) == nullptr) {
            cout << "result is empty" << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
                printf("OfficeCode: %s, city: %s\n", row[0], row[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error message: " << mysql_error(conn) <<":" <<mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
    }
delete conn;
}
```

Comment: Since you're using C++, consider using the C++ Connector, not the extremely feeble C library.

Comment: @tadman I believe i did include it in the properties of the project, but i assume you're referring to the line reading `const char* q = query.c_str();` right? Im just going off the sample code provided by the prof so if there **is** a better edit that i can make i really appreciate the tip there. ill look into it

Comment: I mean the [C++ Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/) library which is completely different from the C one (`mysql_query` and friends).

Comment: Note: MySQL Workbench is a client, not a server. You need a running server on a box where you can connect to (the local box or any other reachable machine).